# How to filter external HTTP requests using on remote host location and GET parameters with Tomcat8?

Tags: security, tomcat, http, request

I have a tomcat 8 web applications server and it has a running application (**/app**). This /app can be accessed from both internal and external HTTP GET requests but 1 request from external should be filtered and returns error if it is not requested from localhost.

The request has this pattern **/app?query=delete&id=a**, it should work if it is http://localhost:8080/app?query=deletel&id=a, **but not** http://domain:8080/app?query=delete&id=a.

How can I do it only with tomcat 8 or firewall if necessary? I'm using Linux system.

Comment: What if I want to trick your system and try an URL `http://domain:8080/app?id=a&query=delete1`?

Comment: @peterh It should throw an error, because this request cannot be done from external.

Comment: Probably there is no builtin servlet filter in Tomcat for that, but it would be easy to implement one.